# Paste outbound phone number in the SMS body

Tags: twilio

I wanted to paste in our customer phone number to a URL as value so we can send them another message after based on their posted review. We're basically going to send them a thank you sms if they posted a thumbs up. If posted a thumbs down, we're going to send them our info on where to forward their concerns. This doesn't seem to work:

[image]

The sms received only has https://review.com/review/google-los-angeles/?p=
without the phone number rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. It should be {{contact.channel.address}}